# Can I get distance between 3 points using Google Directions API?

Tags: api, google-maps, distance, directions

I am trying to get distance between more then 2 points. My code is running fine and I can get between 2 points but I want to get from more then 2 points.
Like:

Point 1 -> Point 2 -> Point 3 -> Point 4

If anyone can help me will be very good, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `more then 2 points`? is that from point 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 to 4? if so you can write a helper function to do it. BTW, are you working on the web? or Android?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I need for web, yes, I want from point 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 to 4. Can you please let me know how to write helper function? Can you please share example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to find distance between 2 points... so you might want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kylelam/t3d7jL64/1/):

```
function distanceOf(points){

if (points.length<2){
    return 0;
}

if (points.length==2){
    //calculate distance between point x to point x+1
    return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[0].x-points[1].x, 2)+Math.pow(points[0].y-points[1].y, 2))
}


total=0;
for (i=0; i < points.length-1; i++){
    total+=distanceOf([points[i],points[i+1]]);
}

return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is not what I need as Google is returning time in format like this:
19 hours 2 minutes
1 day 5 hours

So by 3 distance I was getting that type of values and I can sum up all together to get total time but I need to convert all to same format first that is why I asked this question to get easier way so Google can directly send response like that.

Comment: I think you can either parse the time yourself, like.. 1 hr = 60 mins... etc.. or you can try to see if there are settings

Comment: And that is what I am asking, if there is good way to do that?